# How to create folder and files in google drive using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using google drive SDK for folder creation, but unable to create. I am able to login and get all files and folder but unable to create it.

I am using swift and used this code

```
let metaData = GTLRDrive_File()
    metaData.name = "xyz"
    metaData.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    let querys = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: metaData, uploadParameters: nil)

    querys.fields = "id"

    //service.executeQuery(querys, delegate: self, didFinish: nil)

    self.service.executeQuery(querys) { (ticket:GTLRServiceTicket, object:Any?, error:Error?) in
        // Put your completion code here
    }
```

But unable to create folder. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
    func chilkatTest() {
        var success: Bool = true

    //  It requires the Chilkat API to have been previously unlocked.
    //  See Global Unlock Sample for sample code.

    //  This example uses a previously obtained access token having permission for the
    //  Google Drive scope.

    let gAuth = CkoAuthGoogle()
    gAuth.AccessToken = "GOOGLE-DRIVE-ACCESS-TOKEN"

    let rest = CkoRest()

    //  Connect using TLS.
    var bAutoReconnect: Bool = true
    success = rest.Connect("www.googleapis.com", port: 443, tls: true, autoReconnect: bAutoReconnect)

    //  Provide the authentication credentials (i.e. the access token)
    rest.SetAuthGoogle(gAuth)

    //  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  A multipart upload to Google Drive needs a multipart/related Content-Type
    rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", value: "multipart/related")

    //  Specify each part of the request.

    //  The 1st part is JSON with information about the file.
    rest.PartSelector = "1"
    rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", value: "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    let json = CkoJsonObject()
    json.AppendString("name", value: "testHello.txt")
    json.AppendString("description", value: "A simple file that says Hello World.")
    json.AppendString("mimeType", value: "text/plain")

    //  To place the file in a folder, we must add a parents[] array to the JSON
    //  and list the folder id's.  It's possible for a file to be in multiple folders at once
    //  if it has more than one parent.  If no parents are specified, then the file is created
    //  in the My Drive folder.
    //  Note: We'll assume we already have the id if the folder.  It is the id's that are specified here,
    //  not the folder names.
    var parents: CkoJsonArray? = json.AppendArray("parents")
    var folderId: String? = "0B53Q6OSTWYolY2tPU1BnYW02T2c"
    parents!.AddStringAt(-1, value: folderId)
    parents = nil

    rest.SetMultipartBodyString(json.Emit())

    //  The 2nd part is the file content, which will contain "Hello World!"
    rest.PartSelector = "2"
    rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", value: "text/plain")

    var fileContents: String? = "Hello World!"
    rest.SetMultipartBodyString(fileContents)

    var jsonResponse: String? = rest.FullRequestMultipart("POST", uriPath: "/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
    if rest.LastMethodSuccess != true {
        print("\(rest.LastErrorText)")
        return
    }

    //  A successful response will have a status code equal to 200.
    if rest.ResponseStatusCode.integerValue != 200 {
        print("response status code = \(rest.ResponseStatusCode.integerValue)")
        print("response status text = \(rest.ResponseStatusText)")
        print("response header: \(rest.ResponseHeader)")
        print("response JSON: \(jsonResponse!)")
        return
    }

    //  Show the JSON response.
    json.Load(jsonResponse)

    //  Show the full JSON response.
    json.EmitCompact = false
    print("\(json.Emit())")

    //  A successful response looks like this:
    //  {
//   "kind": "drive#file",
    //    "id": "0B53Q6OSTWYoldmJ0Z3ZqT2x5MFk",
    //    "name": "Untitled",
    //    "mimeType": "text/plain"
    //  }

    //  Get the fileId:
    print("fileId: \(json.StringOf("id"))")

}
```

**Link for libraries needed:-**
[Download libraries](https://chilkatdownload.com/9.5.0.68/chilkat-9.5.0-ios9.zip)

Include CkoAuthGoogle, CkoRest and CkoJsonObject header files in your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply what is CkoAuthGoogle, and how to access accessToken

Comment: CkoAuthGoogle - Provides functionality for authenticating calls to the Google Cloud Platform API and Google Apps API using a service account and
Access Token - the access token to be used in Google API requests. This property is set on a successful call to ObtainAccessToken.

I hope the solution helped you!

Comment: how to download CkoAuthGoogle lib

Comment: Link has been added for the lib.

you can include 3 main header file in your project from include folder :- CkoAuthGoogle, CkoRest and CkoJsonObject

Comment: @Udaikumar did my solution helped you? are you happy with the answer?

Comment: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp check this link and download the proper libraries. The following things worked for my project.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically due to the scope, I have to give kGTLRAuthScopeDriveFile in scope area

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly,kGTLRAuthScopeDriveFile]
```

and rest same in google

```
func folder(){

    let metadata = GTLRDrive_File()
    metadata.name = "eBilling"

    metadata.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    let querys = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: metadata, uploadParameters: nil)
    querys.fields = "id"

    self.service.executeQuery(querys, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLRServiceTicket, object:Any?, error:Error?) in

        if error == nil {

            self.listFiles()

        }
        else {
            print("An error occurred: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

If you are looking to just create a folder without uploading a file with it, 
I was able to create a drive folder using Google's REST endpoint like this.

This function takes the auth token and a filename and parameters to create a URLRequest that can then be sent off within a URLSession.

```
func createFolderRequest(authToken: String, folderName: String) -> URLRequest {

    let headers = [
      "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=123456789",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + authToken
    ]

    let body =
    """
    --123456789
    Content-Type: application/json

    {
      "name": "\(folderName)",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    }

    --123456789--
    """
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    request.addValue(String(body.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    return request
}
```

I referenced the google docs for multipart file uploads [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart)